# Turn strings in list to object(?)

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry for the unclear title, but i basically want to go from this:

```
['StraightPipe', 'BentPipe', 'BentPipe', 'CrossPipe']
```

To this:

```
[StraightPipe, BentPipe, BentPipe, CrossPipe]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What are those objects in the second list?

Comment: @DanielWalker They are class objects

Answer (score 0):

You can access global variables by their names via the `globals` function.

```
g=globals()
first_list=['StraightPipe', 'BentPipe', 'BentPipe', 'CrossPipe']
second_list=[g.get(x) for x in first_list]
```

Comment: I can access the variables, thing is i need to call the variables from the list like:
list[0] to get the function of the first item

Comment: Your original post said that you wanted to create the list.

Comment: I have the list, but they are strings, meaning i cant call them. so i want to convert them from strings to callable objects

Comment: Does my answer not do that for you?  Once you the list, you can easily call the objects.

Comment: Then im kind of back where i started. I didnt describe it in this post but when i call them directly i get this:
[<class 'straight_pipe.StraightPipe'>, <class 'bent_pipe.BentPipe'>, <class 'bent_pipe.BentPipe'>, <class 'cross_pipe.CrossPipe'>]

I solved this by using _ name _, but that added the items to the list in string form.

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by class objects, im new :P But ill explain what im trying to do:
Each of the classes is a block for a game. The blocks go randomly in a list 4 at a time. The 4 blocks in the list will show up on the screen, but in order to draw them on the screen i have to be able to call them from the list with placed.add(pipes[0]((-2,0)))
but since its a list of strings it gives placed.add("StraightPipe"((-2,0))) which cant be called.

Comment: You should create a new question with these details filled in.  Without seeing your code (or at least a [minimal representation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it), we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create yourself the Objects to be able to call an instance

```
class myObject:
    def __init__(self, value):
        this.attribute = value

StraightPipe = myObject(value)
BentPipe = myObject(value)
GrossPipe = myObject(value)

print([StraightPipe, BentPipe, BentPipe, GrossPipe])
```